# Export charts/data into powerpoint and excel from web application

Tags: php, javascript, web-applications, export-to-excel

Charts and Tables display data from database on a webpage. Is there way to export the data and charts as displayed into Excel and Powerpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible using libraries like [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) and [PHPPowerPoint](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPowerPoint), why not take a look at those and then come back if you have any specific problems

Comment: Thanks Mark, I am using highcharts to generate the charts. I saw these libraries recently. I am trying to export multiple charts from a page, I know it is possible but I haven`t figured how though. If you have done something similar please suggest.. Thanks

Comment: Well you're not going to be able to use highcharts, unless you trigger a save to file and embedd the resultant image in the Excel or PowerPoint, or directly create the charts in PHPExcel.... but the easiest way is to have multiple views, one of which renders the data as HTML for your existing sreen, the others to generate the Excel or PowerPoint